# Error: "This webpage has a redirect loop" in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, action-filter

In MVC, I have created custom attribute for Session Timeout, like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // If the browser session or authentication session has expired...
        if (ctx.Session["USER_ID"] == null )
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                   new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "Controller", "Employer" },
                    { "Action", "SessionTimeout" }
            });

        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I mean is when session is time out, it should to redirect to "SessionTimeout" Action method, and I have placed for Controller methods like,

```
 [SessionExpireFilter]
  public class EmployerController : Controller
  {
   //Action Methods   
  }
```

But here, when Session is Timeout, it is going to action method on browser address, but it is displaying like:

```
 This webpage has a redirect loop
```

I don't know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Check your attributes on EmployerController

Comment: what do you mean? is it problem with attributes?

Comment: maybe add [AllowAnonymous]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `SessionTimeout` action causes `OnActionExecuting` in `SessionExpireFilter` to run again, which becomes an infinite loop. You can either:

- Put `SessionTimeout` action in its own controller without the `SessionExpireFilter` attribute
- Put `SessionExpireFilter` attribute to the individual actions except `SessionTimeout`, instead of the controller
- Check if the current action is `SessionTimeout` in your `OnActionExecuting` code and don't perform the redirect (not the best idea because its name can change in the future and cause trouble again).

Comment: I didn't set any loops for SessionTimeout Action method?

Comment: @sanjay not because of the loops, `RedirectToRoute` starts a new HTTP request, which calls filters again, which calls `RedirectToRoute` again, which calls filters again, on and on :)

Comment: Thanks @ssg, Nice explained, i have done wrong to place the action method in same controller where SessionTimeout method is in it. I have placed that Action method in seperate controller it is working fine.